# Image transform in a multi language site gives wrong getUrl()

Tags: multi-environment, image-transforms

I have a multi language site with /nl and /en in my url.

- mysite.dev/nl
- mysite.dev/en

This is my configuration on general.php

```
'mysite.dev' => array(
    'devMode' => true,
    'translationDebugOutput' => false,
    'siteUrl' => array(
        'nl' => '//mysite.dev/nl/',
        'en' => '//mysite.dev/en/',
    ),
    'environmentVariables' => array(
        'siteUrl'        => 'http://mysite.dev/',
        'basePath' => '/Users/lisavandaele/documents/mysite/public/',
        'baseUrl'    => 'http://mysite.dev/'),

),
```

In my asset transform settings I made: thumb (width 120, height 90, crop)

In my twig I use:

```
{% set asset = entry.afbeelding.first() %}
            {% if asset %}
                <img src="{{ asset.getUrl('thumb') }}" width="{{ asset.getWidth('thumb') }}" height="{{ asset.getHeight('thumb') }}" alt="{{entry.title}}" /><br />
             {% endif %}
```

The url he uses is: //mysite.dev/nl/cpresources/transforms/1?x=UeS4gtVAw

if I go to the url without the /nl, I can view the image and I see he is rendered in my assets. ==> //mysite.dev/cpresources/transforms/1?x=UeS4gtVAw

But how can I use the correct url without the language parameter (/nl or /en) so my image transforms and can be viewed on my site.

I tried lots of configs, what am I overlooking? 
I also cleared my cache and images evertime I changed my configuration but nothing worked...

Comment: You defined the variable 'siteUrl' twice in your code. Once as a 'environmentVariables'. maybe craft doesn't like that?

Comment: good point, but that didn't fix it. But after looking at it again. I changed the URL in my settings for my image to {baseURl}img/news/ and that did it!

Comment: Then I guess your image url doesn't work because your standard language has a language segment as well. Normaly the standard language would be just this `'nl' => '//mysite.dev/',`

Comment: it is both, / == nl and /nl == nl. it is solved with the {basaeUrl} in my settings for the image url

Comment: @Lisa. You might want to add this as an answer.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. But adding a {baseUrl} to the resource didn’t help. It actually doesn’t matter what I enter there. It just takes the global siteUrl and prepends it the the transform path like this: `http://domain/en/resources/transforms/...` The correct path would be without the `/en/` bit. Any ideas?